# PyCharm: How to automatically set view to "Debugger"-Tab of Debug-Tool-Window?

Tags: python, user-interface, debugging, view, pycharm

when debugging a script in PyCharm, Pycharm automatically opens the "Console"-Tab of the Debug-Tool-Window.
Instead of this I would like it to open the "Debugger"-Tab, so I can see the variables created up until the breakpoint (see figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fxm6.png))

Any ideas?